# How do i restrict SVN folder?

Tags: svn

I want to allow my SVN folder(repository) only to specific IPs. Is it possible to just put .htaccess file to allow specific ip and deny all?

Comment: How do you access your SVN repository? SVN+SSH? svnserve? Apache?

Comment: What he said - way too little information here.  When you say "folder", do you actually mean "repository"?  What protocol are you using (what he said)?  Seriously, one-line questions like this suck.  If you can't be bothered to think about how to ask a *specific* question, why should anyone spend time trying to answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some thorough answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214886/how-do-i-hide-directories-in-apache-specifically-source-control).

Comment: couldn't actually get this through search, however thanks a lot. This may help my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Put the following lines in your `.htaccess` file.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1
```