# How can I set only internal IPs of the company to be accessible with visualSVN server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am setting up VisualSVN for Subversion server for my company. For the security purpose, How can I set only the internal IPs of the company to be accessible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i restrict SVN folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290372/how-do-i-restrict-svn-folder)

Comment: @DannyBeckett it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup VisualSVN Server to listen on specific interfaces:

1. Start **VisualSVN Server Manager**
2. Open **Properties** for root node
3. Switch to **Network** tab and choose **These IP addresses** radio button
4. Then add your internal IP address using **Add** button.
5. Click **OK**

Another option is to use Windows Firewall to restrict traffic to specific IP addresses. For more information about editing Windows Firewall rules, please read the TechNet article ["Add or Edit Firewall Rule"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.11/cc753558(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Note that this approach only limits the IP addresses that can access VisualSVN Server and affects all users.

See the screenshot.

[image]