# mod_rewrite rules to force www and https over main domain, ignoring 1 folder and 1 other domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've **tried tons** (probably in excess of 250) different rewrite rules but none of them are having the desired effect.

---

**Rules** for ***maindomain.com*** which is a wordpress website with SSL & should run with the prefix `www.`

- Check and force `www.` to the entire domain/folders/subfolders...etc (not just wordpress) **EXCEPT** the folder `testfolder`
- Check and force `https.` to the entire domain/folders/subfolders...etc (not just wordpress) **EXCEPT** the folder `testfolder`

---

**Rules** for ***test.otherwebsite.com*** which is a custom set of pages hosted in `/testfolder/` on the server

- Check and forcefully remove `www.` from the domain `test.otherwebsite.com`
- Check and forcefully changed `https` to `http` from the domain `test.otherwebsite.com`

These rules shouldn't be needed I don't think... if the first set of rules work correctly.

---

Comment: Are you rewrites working at all?  .htaccess needs to first be enabled in apache config, if not already.

Comment: Yes, they work fine I just can't figure out the correct set of rewrites (not very good with them yet)

Comment: Honestly, I would just create two .htaccess files, one for each. There's plenty of copy/paste to force https/www

Comment: Already tried that, for some reason in the second directory the page returns error 500 because of the htaccess file.

Comment: Check your server logs then for detailed info. Also, why not post your rewrites so others can see and point out the error?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use rewrite engine if you have access to main configuration files.

(1) Redirect non www to www. A simpler solution is using VirtualHost directive instead of rewrite engine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName maindomain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.maindomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.maindomain.com
    # ... Your www served here
</VirtualHost>
```

For https, you could just simply copy them and replace the port to 443.

(2) Serve `/testfolder` in a separate VirtualHost directive

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.otherwebsite.com
    # ... anything else
</VirtualHost>
```

For https, change port to 443.

Note that those won't make exception to `/testfolder` if accessed from `www.maindomain.com/testfolder`.

A solution is to move the `testfolder` outside directory served by `www.maindomain.com`. For example

```
/var/www/maindomain <--- directory for www.maindomain.com
/var/www/testfolder <--- directory for test.otherwebsite.com
```

There is a `<DirectoryMatch>` directive to prevent that as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/214908/779320. But I'm afraid it apply globally and so can't be served in any VirtualHost. But you can test it anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^testfolder/ https://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R=301,L]
```

**2)** Then you can use this code in your `/testfolder/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.otherwebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: For some reason the test.otherwebsite domain errors out, the .htaccess file isn't working in that subfolder throwing the error: `Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`